# data.rolling().mean() works in console, but not when run

Tags: python, dataframe, rolling-computation

I try to compute a moving average with the following code :
`mav05 = dataT['close'].rolling(window=5).mean()` on the 'close' values of a list of prices contained in data DataFrame. I intend then to use : `dataTrad['mav05'] = pd.Series(mav05, index = dataTrad.index)`
Both lines work perfectly in console. But when I run it, I  get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax message.

I then tried `dataT['mav05'] = dataT['close'].rolling(window=5).mean()` to replace the two lines. and I get the exact same error message.
What do I do wrong ?
THX for your help ;-)

Full code :

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sq
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# ====   Connecting to SQL DB and loading lists ============
connect = sq.connect('tradData.db')        
cursor = connect.cursor()
tS = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM TRBel20", connect)
dataTrad = tS.rename(columns={"Price Open": "open", "Price Close": "close", "Price High": "high", "Price Low": "low", "Volume": "volume" })
dataTrad.drop(dataTrad[pd.isnull(dataTrad["close"])].index, inplace=True)            # clean DB by dropping all rows where closing price is null
dataTrad.drop(dataTrad[pd.isnull(dataTrad["open"])].index, inplace=True)            # clean DB by dropping all rows where closing price is null

# ====   Adding technical parameters ============
# moving average
mav05 = dataTrad['close'].rolling(window=5).mean()
mav20 = dataTrad['close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
mav60 = dataTrad['close'].rolling(window=60).mean()
# bollinger band
rstd20 = dataTrad['close'].rolling(window=20).std()
bollUpperband = mav20 + 2 * rstd20
bollLowerband = mav20 - 2 * rstd20

dataTrad['mav05'] = pd.Series(mav05, index = dataTrad.index)
dataTrad['mav20'] = pd.Series(mav20, index = dataTrad.index)
dataTrad['BollUp'] = pd.Series(bollUpperband, index = dataTrad.index)
dataTrad['BollDown'] = pd.Series(bollLowerband, index = dataTrad.index)
```

Comment: Please post a block of code demonstrating the problem. Its common for syntax errors to be in the lines above the one flagged. Note that since this is a syntax error the posted code doesn't actually need to execute. We just need something that fails a syntax check when loaded.

Answer (score 0):

A question sent to me made things clear... I had misplaced parenthesis above and the code stopped not because of wrong rolling.mean() syntax but because of previous error.
Thanks so much for the wise private question and sorry to have bothered you ;-)